# what is the point of inherited handles without interprocess communication (ipc)?

Tags: c++, windows, inheritance, handle

From what I have been reading it appears that [handle inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/inheritance) does not do any interprocess communication even between parent and child. Is this true? So you still have to figure out some way of getting the value of the handle from the parent to the child process such as by passing it as the second parameter in CreateProcess() or passing it as a named shared object. If so I am trying to understand what the point of it is.

It doesn't save you the extra step of doing ipc. Saying that the child has in any way 'inherited' the handle seems deceptive to me. What has it inherited? Is it not possible to create a handle with the parent process and just pass it as the second parameter in a call to CreateProcess() anyway? Without using so called 'inheritance'?

To clarify, process A calls CreateProcess() to start process B. I thought that B would gain some benefit in terms of easier ipc by being a child of A, but I have been disappointed. It seems that in order to actually use a so called inherited handle I still have to pass it for instance as a parameter to CreateProcess. Like CreateProcess("myprog.exe", myhandle,...), but it seems like I could just pass myhandle there anyway even without inheritance. I am trying to figure out what the point of it is.

Comment: Kinda unclear to me. Could you show some sample code ? (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for what we expect from you)

Comment: Handle inheritance only creates a handle *usable by another process*, it does not magically pass this handle to target process.

Comment: So basically it just saves you a single call to something like OpenProcess()? What does that remote handle creation actually buy you?

Comment: If the handle is not inheritable and you pass it to another process, then it won't be able to use it.